# How to draw millions of points on google maps?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have millions of points I want to draw on google maps coming from an array.

I was looking at [circles example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple)

However, the problem is circles are... circles. Is there some way to draw circles such that it is like a canvas so it doesnt really matter how many points I draw on it?

Comment: Have you seen the article [Too Many Markers!](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) in the Google Documentation?

Comment: Grid-based Clustering looks great, but the docs dont show any examples of how to implement this. I was originally thinking some sort of canvas so that its just coloring pixels. I don't care about being able to interact with mouse.

Comment: By interact, I mean with interact with the point drawn.

Comment: You need to make the question more specific to get a good answer. If you are looking for a heatmap the Google Maps API JS has one: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap , if you like the marker clusterer, but simply do not want the icons the solution is simple, just use https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus and update the calculate function:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783250/modifying-markerclusterer-icons-for-top-score-rather-than-marker-count

Answer (score 6):

There are ready solutions for marker clustering like Markerclusterer or Markerclustererplus.

You can find these libraries on github:

https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclusterer

https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus

Sample pages and documentation are inside these repositories. Could it work for you?

Comment: This does not work for me as this groups all the markers into something that shows a number. I am looking to have a heatmap based on the points available. Markerclusterer does not give me an image that reflects that.

Comment: @Rolando So basically this...? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer Just pass in a bunch of data points and it will draw the heatmap for you.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the answer is don't.  That's too many markers.  Per the table below (grabbed from [geek.com](http://www.geek.com/laptop-screen-size-resolution/)) you would have a screen with nothing but markers and no map, even if each marker were only 1 pixel each, which they aren't.

[image]